# Rust assembly of Option<i32>

Tags: assembly, rust, godbolt

[image]This code compiled with  `-C opt-level=3` in https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/jqEjasPTW

```rust
#[no_mangle]
pub fn match1(num: i32) -> i32 {
   if num == 10 {99} else {11}
}

#[no_mangle]
pub fn match2(num: Option<i32>) -> i32 {
    match num {
        Some(a) => a,
        _ => 11
    }
}
```

produces this assembly code:

```
match1:
        cmp     edi, 10
        mov     ecx, 99
        mov     eax, 11
        cmove   eax, ecx
        ret

match2:
        cmp     edi, 1
        mov     eax, 11
        cmove   eax, esi
        ret
```

why in match2 compares the register edi with 1 ?

Comment: Presumably that is where the discriminant for `Option` is stored, and it's checking if the value is `Some`.

Comment: Because `edi` is where the enum's tag gets passed for that function, and that has to be tested in order to perform the conditional move?

Comment: When linking to https://godbolt.org/, use the "full link" button in the top right to make a link to your actual code in compileable form.  Not a screenshot and a link to the Godbolt front page!  ([full links mostly mitigate link rot](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319549/how-are-we-supposed-to-post-godbolt-links-now-that-url-shortening-is-blocked/319594#319594))